# Problema con un elemento que no se encuentra

Tags: javascript, json, dom

Tengo un problema con un elemento que se encuentra en una página en específico, pero al compartir en el footer, los dos script uno que contiene el elemento y otro que no, en el resto de paginas me manda un error. ¿Alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

Este es el elemento que se encuentra en un script

```
const cuerpo=document.querySelector('#imUno ul');
```

Este seria el error al ejecutarse en una pagina que no existe por el hecho de compartir el script en el footer[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No todos pueden ver las imágenes: muestra el error y el código _como texto, con formato_. Además, especifica en el título _qué error_ da. Lee [ask].

Comment: Creo que te has equivocado de elemento... el problemático es uno represetnado por la variable `cuerpo` segun el error.  Debes agregar en la pregunta donde defines ese elemento y lo que haces con el para poderte ayudar mejor.

Comment: Ahora has puesto el elemento, pero no has puesto que haces con el. Sin verlo cuesta más ayudar, pero a groso modo, hagas lo que hagas con el deberias encerrarlo en un condicional que empiece con `if(cuerpo != null) {` y al final de las acciones que hagas con el mismo cerrarlo con `}`.

Comment: muchas gracias masterguru, con la linea que me dijiste consegui solucionarlo. muchas gracias de nuevo